# log.Println not working with os.Exit(1) for makefile

Tags: go, makefile

I have a command line tool in Go, example:

```
err := doSomething()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err) //fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

In the **makefile**, I am doing:

```
V = 0
Q = $(if $(filter1, $V),,@)
.PHONY: dosomething
dosomething: ; $(info $(shell printf "running dosomething")) @
    $Q cd $(BASE) && ret=0 \
          test -z "$$($(dosomething))" || ret = 1 ; \
       exit $$ret
```

**make** fails (if error occurs) when using `fmt.Println(err)`, but doesn't print anything. When I use `log.Println`, it prints the error but **make** continues. How to fail **make** as well print the error? Also, what to do in the case of a [panic()](https://gobyexample.com/panic) in golang code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this makefile at all.  What is `$(info $(shell printf "running dosomething"))` supposed to do?  Why not just `$(info running dosomething)`?  In general you never want to use make's `shell` function inside a recipe, it just leads to confusion.

Second, it looks like your formatting is wrong because you've put the `@` at the end of the line.

Also you need a semicolon after `ret=0`.

Finally, what is `$$($(dosomething))` supposed to do?  You've not set the make variable `dosomething` to any value, so this is basically a no-op.

I can only assume that in your real makefile you set the make variable `dosomething` to the command you want to run.  It's helpful when asking questions, that you provide the actual files that reproduce the issue (creating a small repro case if the real file is too large or complex).

In that case the reason for the confusion is easy; when you run `$(dosomething)` in the shell it runs the `dosomething` program and captures its stdout and expands to that string... so the output *is not printed*.  It's captured.  For example:

```
$ echo hi
hi
$ foo=$(echo hi)
$ echo $foo
hi
```

Note how `hi` was not printed in the second command because it was captured and stored in the `foo` variable.

On the other hand, `$(...)` does not capture stderr, only stdout:

```
$ echo hi 1>&2
hi
$ foo=$(echo hi 1>&2)
hi
$ echo $foo
```

Note here that `hi` was printed (to stdout) and not captured (so `foo` is now empty).

I don't know much about Go but I can only assume that one of the two functions you show prints to stdout, and the other prints to stderr.

You don't want to capture any output and compare that, instead you want to compare the exit code of the program.  You can do it like this:

```
V = 0
Q = $(if $(filter1, $V),,@)
.PHONY: dosomething
dosomething = <command-to-run>
dosomething:
        $(info running dosomething)
        $Q cd $(BASE) && $(dosomething)
```

This allows the output of the `dosomething` command to run without capturing any output, and it will exit with the exit code of the command, which will be 0 on success and not-0 (1 in your case) on error.